# Is a sort of "z-drift" the result of numerical precision errors in FDM?

Tags: pde, finite-difference

Upon solving the 2D wave equation with Neumann boundary conditions $u_x = u_y = 0$ on a rectangular $10 \times 10 \times 10$ grid, I noticed something odd - $u$ seemed to shift upwards with time. This can be demonstrated with the following plot of two time slices:

[image: Z-shift in plot]

In fact, the value of $u(x, y, t)$ shifted on average 10 units up during the simulation. Is this due to numerical precision errors, or perhaps taking overly large time steps? Or is there another reason for this "z-shift"?

Comment: Does the amount of drift change when you refine your timesteps? If the drift persists irrespective of the stepsize then you propably have a bug in your code.

Comment: I've tested it, but it doesn't depend on time step size

Comment: What happens when you reduce your grid to a single cell? In that case there should be no spatial dynamics at all. If you keep seeing your drift there I would take a closer look at your timestepping scheme.

Comment: I keep seeing a drift still. I am however pretty sure this is related to my timestepping scheme, as when I change the time span of integration, the error decreases.

Comment: Depending on how you implemented the Neumann boundary conditions, you might be experiencing artificial reflection. Have you tried using ghost cells?

Comment: This appeared even before adding in any boundary conditions whatsoever, so I doubt it is due to the Neumann boundary conditions

Comment: Does it happen before the wave reaches the boundary or after? What happens if you make the domain let's say 10 times larger? Do you still see the same amount of increase in the same time frame?